# Text classification in Accord.net, 12000 features, index out of bounds?

Tags: machine-learning, indexoutofboundsexception, accord.net

Exception is "Index was outside the bounds of the array." at line :learner.Learn(inputs, outputs).

Ive checked my input and output array so many times, I cant for the life of me work out whats wrong here. Ive also tried it in SVM with the same error.

Reading stack overflow there are a few people who have run into the same error, but I have not been able to implement their fixes to my code.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQROL.png)

Comment: Hi there - do you think you could post a .zip with a small project that reproduces the issue you've encountered to the project's issue tracker at https://github.com/accord-net/framework ? I guess this would make it easier to debug and eventually fix this problem in a next release! Thanks a lot!